# logback, How to change message in logging event before appending

Tags: logging, logback, slf4j

Using logback 1.2.3 and Java 9...

Googled around trying to find a built-in way to alter the log message before it hits an appender.  Is the only way through an encoder slash layout?  Basically looking for the something like enrichment as provided by Serilog where you can alter a message (event) before it drops into a sink.

Here is the use case: before a log event makes it's way to an appender a hook is needed to at least alter the message text.

Comment: Here is another use case, not covered by the answers given so far: Need to scan log messages for PII information and either transform or remove that information before it gets logged to a SocketAppender (where PatternLayout does not apply).

Comment: @user2957009 MessageConverter returns the formatted message. So you can use the accepted answer to do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Logback's [`PatternLayout`](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/PatternLayout.html#defaultConverterMap) contains `defaultConverterMap` which maps conversion words (`%msg`, `%n`, `%ex` etc) to implementations of `ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.Converter`.

You could provide your own implementation of `MessageConverter` and associate it with a custom conversion word as follows:

1. Add this to `logback.xml`

   ```
    <!-- using mx to imply 'message extended' -->
    <conversionRule conversionWord="mx" converterClass="some.package.CustomMessageConverter" />
   ```
2. Implement `some.package.CustomMessageConverter` as follows:

   ```
    import ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.MessageConverter;
    import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;

    public class CustomMessageConverter extends MessageConverter {

        public String convert(ILoggingEvent event) {
            return enhance(super.convert(event));
        }

        // implement your "hook ... to at least alter the message text"
        private String enhance(String incoming) {
            // ...
        }
    }
   ```
3. Update your encoder pattern to use the conversion word `mx`:

   ```
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}|[%thread]|[%X{complexNestedValue:-NA}]|%-5level|%logger{36}|%mx %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
   ```

With these changes in place your custom converter will be engaged and the output will include whatever `CustomMessageConverter.convert` returns for each log event

Comment: Perfect.  Just saw that Spring uses the same pattern with message converters.  Shame that only conversion rules are passed by class name references (i.e. **ctx.putObject(CoreConstants.PATTERN_RULE_REGISTRY, conversionRules);**) rather than being able to provide an object instance.  For example if I wanted to have a custom message converter that had a constructor with parameters.

Comment: Hi @glytching, I have the exact piece of code for my masking and I do have a problem with it (or I think so). I need to find a way to mask some data from a Throwable's error stack.  The `MessageConveter` only returns the `formattedMessage` that is the string plus optional values given as an array. But I cannot find a Converter that will mask both the message and the full error stack (that contains the root cause of the Exception). Using the `ThrowableProxyConverter` will drop the formattedMessage. Have you encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 3):

Just extending on glytching's answer, you can pass a Spring property to the `CustomMessageConverter` if required.

In your `application.yml`

`my.logging.properties: PropertyOne, PropertyTwo`

In your `logback.xml`

`<springProperty scope="context" name="myLoggingPoperties" source="my.logging.properties"/>`

Your encoder pattern becomes

```
<encoder>
    <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}|[%thread]|[%X{complexNestedValue:-NA}]|%-5level|%logger{36}|%mx{${myLoggingPoperties}} %n</pattern>
</encoder>
```

The properties are available as a `List<String>` in your `CustomMessageConverter`

```
// implement your "hook ... to at least alter the message text"
private String enhance(String incoming) {
  List<String> properties = getOptionList();
  // ...
}
```